# Erro de relacionamento entre entidades 1:N utilizando orphanRemoval

Tags: java, web-service, spring, spring-boot, restful

Estou tentando atualizar um registro no banco de dados através de um serviço REST com o auxilio do postman, porem está me retornando um erro:

`"A collection with cascade=\"all-delete-orphan\" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: spring.restful.model.Pessoa.telefones; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade=\"all-delete-orphan\" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: spring.restful.model.Pessoa.telefones",`

Segue o código abaixo **ENDPOINT:**

```
@PutMapping("/{cpf}")
public ResponseEntity<Pessoa> atualizar(@PathVariable String cpf, @RequestBody Pessoa pessoa){
    Pessoa existente = pessoas.findById(cpf).get();
    if(existente == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(pessoa , existente, "cpf");
    pessoas.save(existente);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(existente);
}
```

Classe **Pessoa:**

```
@Entity
public class Pessoa implements Serializable {

@Id
private String cpf;

private String nome;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="pessoa", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Telefone> telefones = new ArrayList<Telefone>();

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}

public void setCpf(String cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}

public List<Telefone> getTelefones() {
    return telefones;
}

public void setTelefones(List<Telefone> telefones) {
    this.telefones = telefones;
}
```

Classe **Telefone:**

```
@Entity
public class Telefone implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String numero;

@JsonIgnore
@ForeignKey(name="pessoa_cpf")
@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL)
private Pessoa pessoa;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNumero() {
    return numero;
}

public void setNumero(String numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
}

public Pessoa getPessoa() {
    return pessoa;
}

public void setPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
    this.pessoa = pessoa;
}
```

**OBS: Sem usar o atributo do tipo List<> o metodo `BeanUtils.copyProperties` funciona corretamente sem nenhum erro.**

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Seu problema está na camada DAO, bem aonde foi feita as anotações JPA (Hibernate), no erro deve estar descrevendo qual entidade está o problema

Comment: qual o relacionamento das tabelas? 1:n, 1:1 ou n:n, isso influencia na utilização de coleção(List) ou não.

Comment: Por favor, edita sua pergunta e coloca as informações

Comment: Qual versão do framework do spring-boot você está usando? Postei uma resposta, se não der certo responde aqui que arrumo ou apago.

Comment: ` <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>`

Comment: fiz o download da ultima versao do site https://spring.io/tools para windows

Answer (score 1):

Experimente trocar a anotação `@ForeignKey(name="pessoa_cpf")` por 
`@JoinColumn(name="pessoa_cpf")`, e remova a configuração cascata recursiva , `cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL` da classe Telefone.

```
@Entity
public class Telefone implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String numero;

@JsonIgnore
@JoinColumn(name="pessoa_cpf")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Pessoa pessoa;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNumero() {
    return numero;
}

public void setNumero(String numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
}

public Pessoa getPessoa() {
    return pessoa;
}

public void setPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
    this.pessoa = pessoa;
}
```

Comment: o erro persiste!

Comment: fiz uma alteração na resposta

Comment: ainda continua o mesmo erro